# Regex Python - How to get the number of occurences that are not consecutives?

Tags: python, regex

Here's my code, I'd like to get the number of combinations based on this pattern : `x - y - x` , example : `"UBU" , "ANA", "INI"`

```
    import re 

    pattern = r"(?P<name>[a-z]).(?P=name)"

    print(len(re.findall(pattern, "hello"))) # should return 0 : OK

    print(len(re.findall(pattern, "mirror"))) # should return 1 because there is "ror" : OK 

    print(len(re.findall(pattern, "irir"))) #should return 2 because there are "iri" and "rir" : return just 1
```

It's not working when part of the combinations is imbricated into another one like the first two letters of "rir" in "iri".

Would you know how to get the correct number of those combinations (for the third example) ?
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: The term imbricated is specific to *botany*. If you want to find some useful information you must look for the term *overlapping*.

Comment: Thanks , I'm not english so I was searching the term to use :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def pattern_counter(word):
    return sum([1 for index, letter in enumerate(word[:(len(word)-2)]) if letter == word[index+2]])

word1 = "hello"
word2 = "mirror"
word3 = "irir"

print(pattern_counter(word1)) # prints 0
print(pattern_counter(word2)) # prints 1
print(pattern_counter(word3)) # prints 2
```